# matlab parfor not working

Tags: matlab, parfor

This code is working without parfor but not working with parfor

```
load ('../segment.mat');
accuracy = zeros(30,1);
l=1;
parfor k = 1 : 2 : 9
    for p = 0.5 : 0.5 : 3
         if p ~= 0
            pred = run_1_KNN(k , p , X);
            accuracy(l,1)  = mean(strcmp(pred', y.train));
            l= l + 1;           
         end
    end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could quote and describe the error when you use `parfor`.

Comment: You need to open the pool.

Comment: Did you open up a pool of workers yet?  Try doing `matlabpool` or `parpool` before you run this code.

Comment: @rayryeng yeah I used the command matlabpool

Comment: @OlegKomarov I did open the matlabpool

Comment: @Hoki The error is   Error using main (line 4)
Error: The variable accuracy in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry man I am new to StackOverflow and this my first question :/ Error is Error using main (line 4)
Error: The variable accuracy in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Comment: @rayryeng apology accepted,yeah I saw the link and I think there is an issue with array. parfor do not work with array like normal for but how to do it with parfor or is this impossible?

Comment: @Hassan - I know why.  Let me write an answer

Comment: @Hassan - Done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your `parfor` isn't working is because the `accuracy` variable is being accessed in a synchronous way.  This behaviour will work assuming that you are going to iterate through the call of `run_1_KNN` using a single thread, which is why using just a `for` works rather than `parfor`.  Because of the fact that you have a **nested** `for` loop call within your `parfor`, this relies on work done in previous iterations.  `parfor` **cannot** have this behaviour and it works in an asynchronous matter.  Each thread performs work that should be independent of other threads.

If you want to use `parfor` (a.k.a. multiple threads), you have to be able to access `accuracy` in a way that is asynchronous.  What I would suggest you do is create values of `k` and `p` in unique pairings outside of your `parfor` loop.  You would then use a single `parfor` to access each unique pair of `k` and `p`, and then access your `accuracy` array.  What I'll do for you is create a final matrix that has the first column as `k`, the second column as `p` and the third column as the accuracy values.  As such, for each row of this matrix, it gives you what `k`, `p`, and what the accuracy is for that particular triple.  As such:

```
[karray, parray] = meshgrid(1 : 2 : 9, 0.5 : 0.5 : 3);
karray = karray(:);
parray = parray(:);
accuracy = zeros(numel(karray), 1);
parfor idx = 1 : numel(karray)
    k = karray(idx);
    p = parray(idx);
    pred = run_1_KNN(k , p , X);
    accuracy(idx)  = mean(strcmp(pred', y.train));        
end

final_mat = [karray parray accuracy];
```

Take note that I removed the condition with the `if` statement as there will never be a value of `p` that is equal to 0.  The code inside the `if` statement will always run, so I decided to remove that to be cleaner.  This code should now run, and should be independent of any previous iterations in a `for` loop.  This should also run asynchronously.  `final_mat` contains that final matrix I talked about from before.

---

Hope this helps.  Good luck!